# Failed to compile error in react while trying to run the folder on terminal

Tags: reactjs

Initially the react was working fine as i follow the tutorial but I decided to keep my folder organized and copy the create-react-app folder to another folder and it does not work properly again.

I tried to check the tutorial am watching if i miss anything or do things wrongly but codes is ok. and I then tried to re install a new version of Node.js and npm. this upgrade the version of what i was using before.

```
import React from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';
import { robot } from './robots';
import './App.css';
const state = {
    robotss: robots,
    searchfield: ''
}

class App extends component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            robots: robots,
            searchfield: ''
        }
    }

    onSearchChange = (event) => {
        this.setstate({ searchfield.event.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robots => {
            return robots.name,toLowercase().inludes(this.state.searchfield.toLowercase());
        })
        return (
        <div className='tc' >
        <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange} />
        <CardList robots = {filteredRobots}/>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Expected result is to compiled and display the robots app.

Failed to compile
./src/index.js
  Line 5:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

3 | import './index.css';
  4 | import App from './App';

> 5 | import as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
>       |           ^
>     6 | import 'tachyons';
>     7 | 
>     8 | ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));
>   This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.